# Add onClick for outbound links that don't have it

Tags: javascript, onclick

I want to add `onClick=""` for links (in content and comments) of type bit.ly, j.mp and domain.com/go/ that don't have it already so that links look like:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/go/best-house/" rel="external nofollow" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'click', 'ps', 'http://domain.com/go/best-house/']);">link text</a>
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use plain JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a'),
        addGaqPush = function() {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'click', 'ps', 'event_house']);
    };
    for( var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++ ) {
        elements[i].onclick = addGaqPush;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. But how to adapt it to work only on links of type bit.ly, j.mp, and domain.com/go/ ? I think that the code obove will work for all links.

Comment: I think I'll try to use http://colintemple.com/writing/2010/08/event-tracking-jquery/